# Responsive Website runs properly on simulator but not on actual devices

Tags: html, responsive

I built responsive website which I wanted to be run on mobile devices and for that I wrote  media query also. I give my html format here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
...<!-- meta tags,scripts for mobile devices as well as others-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="home container-fluid">
...  <!-- my first page-->
</div>

<div class="home container-fluid">
... <!-- my second page -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any change that I must do in HTML?
this code works properly with desktop version and when I do inspect element on google chrome, it looks proper for all devices but not work when I tested on actual mobile device. Suppose, I wrote media query for iphone6 plus as follow:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and 
(max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape)
 {
   ...// styles for various classes and ids for landscape of iphone6+
 }

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and 
(max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait)
  {
   ... // styles for portrait mode in iphone6+
  }
```

Now, if I check by inspect element in chrome and check for  iphone6+, it looks properly but if I tried on actual iphone 6+ then it not worked well. 
What can I do so that my website runs properly on actual devices. Currently, it only works for simulators.

Comment: Are you simulator looking at a live website or a local development server? Make sure your "real" devices are not using cached style sheets. Use a [CacheBuster](http://twosixcode.com/notes/view/simple-cache-busting-for-css-and-js) if needed. "Then it not worked well", please expand on this, did it not work at all? If it some of it work detail what didn't work as expected and how it differd.

Comment: Screenshots/pictures of the simulators versus real devices would be helpful

Comment: If you have an android device with chrome installed, you can debug your website on real device via desktop chrome. Conect your android phone to your pc with USB, check `system setting > developer options > usb debug` on,  open website in chrome, go to desktop chrome open `chrome://inspect`, you will see tabs opened in android.

Comment: @catssay it doesn't work